# How to open contact form 7 by using wordpress ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

I am using contact from 7 plugin and my question is to open contact form 7 in popup via wordpress admin ajax but my code not working. Only popup open but contact form 7 not submitting. It is redirecting in admin ajax url and returns 0.

Here is the code that i am doing in functions.php

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'my_action_popup_cf7_javascript');

function my_action_popup_cf7_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.myajaxcarrer').click(function(){
      //alert(1);
      var mydata = $(this).data();
      $(".overlay").fadeIn('slow');       
        var data = {
            action: 'my_action_popup_cf7',
            //whatever: 1234,
            id: mydata.id
        };
        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        //console.log(ajaxurl);
        $('.item').removeClass('active');
        $('[data-id=' + mydata.id + ']').parent().addClass('active');
        $.post('<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
           // alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
           $('#testcarrer').html(response);
            var offset = $(window).scrollTop();

            $(".career-form").css("top", offset+50 );

            $('.closeBtn').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $(".overlay").fadeOut('slow');
              $('.career-form').css("top", -1000+"%" )
            });
        });
    });
});

</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action_popup_cf7', 'my_action_popup_cf7_callback');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_popup_cf7', 'my_action_popup_cf7_callback' );

function my_action_popup_cf7_callback() {
     global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
     //$whatever = 'ID=> '. $_POST['id'];
     //echo $whatever;
     ?>
     <a href="#" class="closeBtn">X</a>
      <h3>Apply Now</h3>
      <div class="formBox">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="905" title="My New Carrer Form"]'); ?>
      </div>
     <?php
     exit(); // this is required to return a proper result & exit is faster than die();
}
```

And code in page template file is

```
<span class="applyBtn"><a class="myajaxcarrer" data-id="903">Apply Now</a></span>

<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="career-form">Ajax result Load here..</div>
```

And js code is below.

```
$('.applyBtn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(".overlay").fadeIn('slow'); 
  $(".career-form").css("top", offset+50 )
});

$('.closeBtn, .overlay').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".overlay").fadeOut('slow');
  $('.career-form').css("top", -1000+"%" )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open it by echoing do_shortcode('[form name with id]'); it in you php function.